# ubercart - many "in checkout" orders

Tags: 6, ubercart

I have a problem that too many of the orders coming in don't get completed and remain in checkout. It appears as though it doesn't even try to send to paypal.

I don't think that the issue is that the form is failing validation because of 2 reasons:

1. wouldn't most of these people try to correct their info and submit again?
2. i have also javascript validation on the page.

This issue has been with me for quite some time, and I would LOVE to get rid of it...

Answer (score 1):

In checkout is a stage when someone adds something to the cart but does not go through the checkout process. It has nothing to do with the way your site functions. Just the user didn't want to checkout.

This problem (most likely) is Shopping Cart Abandonment (Google it).

UC Followup is a module that helps users push through "Adondoned Carts".
http://www.drupalmodules.com/module/ubercart-followup

Comment: I have the same problem. The functionality is all good. Only thing is if someone fills in invalid fields on the checkout page, he stays on the checkout page and the order is still logged in to "in checkout" mode.

Now if this person fills in the correct information clicks review order again, second order is created "in checkout".

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind to alter the core code there is a solution http://www.ubercart.org/forum/support/6399/many_incomplete_orders_in_checkout_status_what_could_it_be